# How can I remove line continuation markers from a Python email.Message object's get_payload call?

Tags: python, email

In a test harness, I am trying to verify that a certain identifier appears in an email message. The message has been parsed from a file using Python's built-in email.message_from_file() method.

When I retrieve the message content using get_payload, it is broken across several lines and includes line continuation markers (the = character as the last character in the line). Unfortunately, the identifier I am looking for is split across a line break.

While I *could* change the textual part of message to avoid the identifier getting split, I would prefer to find a good mechanism to recombine the continued lines and recover the original string. Can anyone suggest a good way to do so?

Comment: Are you trying to form an email Message object from a file?  If so, be aware that email.message_from_file() will parse the file according to RFC2822 standards where the '=' character has a special meaning. Each line in the file, delimited by CRLF/'\r\n', is parsed as a _part of an email_ in the form FIELD = VALUE. The unexpected result your getting from get_payload() is a symptom of improper parsing.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. The email file in question was generated from within the context of python (actually Django - a class based on EmailMultiAlternatives). The response to get_payload does accurately match what is present in the file. Does that mean the file is malformed, or should the parser have recognized and removed the continuation characters?

Comment: Sorry, a bit rusty on the email part regarding '=' (reviewing RFC2822, it is ':' that's the FIELD: VALUE). Assuming that the file is compliant to standards, if you were looking for those KEY=VALUE in the **body** of the email, check first if the Message object is_multipart(). If True, you need to isolate the body. If False, you can right away call get_payload() and get a string. get_payload will return string representations of attachments and other parts of the email. You have to do a mail.walk() to isolate the body from a multipart email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'blah blah iden=\ntifier blah blah'
>>> print s
blah blah iden=
tifier blah blah
>>> s.replace('=\n', '')
'blah blah identifier blah blah'
>>> s.replace('=\n', '').find('identifier')
10
```

Comment: D'oh! Yes, of course.

For anyone coming along later, the entire line necessary is:
decoded = email.get_payload([Payload index, if necessary]).as_string().replace('=\n','')

Comment: This might not be the way to go. If you were forming the email from the file (see my comment on your question above), this answer will correct what you see/get from get_payload() but the email object is still malformed.

Answer (score 3):

*For all late comers to the party:* Use the `decode` flag for the [get_payload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload) method:

```
email.get_payload(decode=True)
```

This strips the `=` signs as continuation markers at the end of line properly, because it does so only when the appropriate header `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` is set.